# How to read all files in directory iteratively in Java?

Tags: java, file, nio

I have a directory on network drive with million of files. If I try to read it with

```
folder.listFiles()
```

it will take a lot of time until resulting array will be filled with files.

I would like to receive files by one and printout a progress.

How can I do this in Java?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try with [`DirectoryStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html):

```
Path dir = Paths.get("C:\\"); // directory to list

try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir)) {
    for (Path entry: stream) {
        System.out.println(entry);
    }
} catch (DirectoryIteratorException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can also make the `DirectoryStream` filter files for you if you need to: all you need to do is add a parameter to the `Files.newDirectoryStream` call:

```
DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.{txt,png,jpg}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NIO.2 API:

```
try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/path/to/directory"))) {
    for (Path path : directoryStream) {
        System.out.println(path.toString());
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {}
```